# Screen program splits window but unable to use or type

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnu-screen, window

I want to use the `screen` program to run sessions on my terminal and split my terminal. But both in horizontal and vertical split, when the window splits into two, I'm not able to use or type in the second window that just split. See attached pics. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and my `screen` version is 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20.

[Horizontal split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H75Q5.png)
[Vertical split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLVeU.png)

Answer (score 3):

Pressing Ctrl-a Tab will switch you between screens. If you want to open a shell in the new split screen, use Ctrl-a c

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I have tried both these commands, I am able to switch and create shells but in the split shell it looks the same where I am not able to type or use it

Comment: you did switch to the second screen before creating a shell?

Comment: Just to add, the correct way for switching between screen windows is by using `C-a SPACE`. Refer to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [this cheat sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/screen.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with either your shell, your terminal any other program that could be interfering with your inputs.
An alternative way would be to use screen windows.

Relevant commands:

- `C-a c` Create a window
- `C-a n` or `C-a <space>` Change to next window in list

Additional commands includes:

- `C-a C-a` Switch to last-visited window ("flip-flop")
- `C-a <number>` Change to window by number
- `C-a k` Kill current window

Note: `C-a` is `Ctrl + A`

Refer to the GNU screen manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).